# Calculating Great Circle track using latitude and longitude in Excel

Tags: excel, navigation, trigonometry, degrees, radians

I'm trying to calculate the initial bearing (forward azimuth) between two positions using latitude and longitude. After much googling most of what I can find either relates to calculating distance, or calculates using an equirectangular projection.

The closest I could find is the formula:

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
```

which when using excel needs to be reversed:

```
=ATAN2(COS(lat1)*SIN(lat2)-SIN(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon2-lon1),SIN(lon2-lon1)*COS(lat2))
```

The output *should* give me the answer in radians, which I convert to degrees using:

```
=MOD(DEGREES(answer)+360,360)
```

However I'm not getting anything that makes sense.

My test points are located in the southern hemisphere: **-17.9467 122.2350** and **-20.3783 118.6233**

I should be getting an answer of about 232 degrees (there's 1-2 degrees of magnetic variation in this answer whereas the formula is in degrees True), however I'm getting 177 degrees.

Can anyone see my (probably simple) error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the original data to radians before using the formula.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. It never clicked in my head that the figures I entered for latitude and longitude were in decimal **degrees**!